# Div won't stretch because it's containing element is set to min-height

Tags: html, height, footer, sticky, css

I'd like a div to stretch the height of the page, which it will if it and it's containing elements are all set to "height:100%;"

However, in order to my sticky footer to work, I need the container to be set to "min-height:100%;". Apparently the height of min-height isn't inherited. Solution?

Can I:

1) Stretch the div while keeping it's parent set to min-height instead of height?

2) Is there a solution which will set the footer to sticky without the use of min-height?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand what your issue is, and if it's the same one that I've experienced in the past then hopefully this will help.

In the div you have the min-height set, try adding:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work :( It seems the problem is due to a lack of inheretence of height from min-height properties. Seems there SHOULD be a way around this.